# Http response time with nodejs compression is taking more time than without compression

Tags: node.js, http, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to perform a load test with jmeter on my nodejs server. I found that the average http request response times for N concurrent user and the standard deviation is longer when using compression module than without using it. Is this something normal and what could the reason for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression benefits you when the bandwidth speedup from delivering fewer bits by compressing is more important than the extra CPU that the compression takes.  If you're running a local test over a fast network, then the bandwidth savings of compression may not be able to overcome the extra CPU load that the compression takes.

A local network test may not be representative of what would happen between a real set of clients and your server over a longer internet link that isn't as fast as a local network.

The slower the network link, the bigger the difference the compression might make.  It also depends upon how large the http responses are.  Small responses will not benefit much from compression either.  Large responses have much more of a chance of benefiting from compression and even more on slower links.

Comment: @Ahmed - I added a bit more about the size of the http response.

Comment: I'm desperately looking for some kind of research paper or graph that outlines the relationship between link speed, response size, and benefits to overall rendering latency when compression is on vs. off.  In particular, with regards to small and rapid-fire API calls.  Anyone have any links?

Comment: Could you please suggest how do we compare gzip/compression results in our local dev env.

Comment: @CuriousCurie - What do you mean compare?  My answer itself explains that locally, gzip probably doesn't make as much difference because latency is low and bandwidth is high.  So testing it locally isn't going to really tell you anything useful you could apply  to an actual deployment.  Test your real deployment environment if there's something you want to know.